# Type mismatch error when saving with timestamp

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

My code below stops at the "SaveAs" line with a type mismatch error, any idea why? I really need to have the date in a YYYY-MM-DD format. I had code that worked but it would show single digit months and days as a single digit, instead of 04.

```
Sub save2()
'APAC
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim xStrDate As String
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
xStrDate = VBA.Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APAC_Coming_Due").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APAC_Overdue").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APACCover").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.Sheets(1).Name = "APAC - IMPORTANT INFORMATION"
wb.Sheets(2).Name = "Overdue"
wb.Sheets(3).Name = "Due Date Approaching"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete


wb.SaveAs"\\xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.com\xxxxxx\xxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx_
\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\APAC OverdueOutstanding & " - " & xStrDate.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: A line continuation underscore cannot be inside the string like you have it, and you will want to also specify a file type spcification that matches your file extension in your `SaveAs`.

Comment: Your `xStrDate` variable is also "inside of your string" which it should not be.  Could just be an issue with quotes. Start by putting that whole part on one line instead and get that working before you try breaking it into 2, if you really need it on 2.

Comment: the line break was just for stack overflow. In the actual code its one line.

Comment: Probably better to not do that in the future then. Stack Overflow will add a scrollbar automatically as you can see in Peh's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate your strings and variables correctly using `&` outside a string not inside!

And if you have line breaks you need to end the string with `" & _` and start a new string in the next line:

```
wb.SaveAs "\\xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.com\xxxxxx\xxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx" & _ 
          "\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\APAC OverdueOutstanding - " & xStrDate & ".xlsx"
wb.Close
```

or have everything in one line:

```
wb.SaveAs "\\xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.com\xxxxxx\xxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\APAC OverdueOutstanding - " & xStrDate & ".xlsx"
wb.Close
```

Comment: @PEH The line break was just for stack overflow but it was the quotation marks thanks!